# How to print last two matched string from file

Tags: python

I need to print a file's last two lines which are getting matched to '`sample`' or '`another`'.  Currently I am using the following code which works as per requirement. But I need to know if there is any way to shorten this more.

```
LOG_FILE = "foo"
for line in reversed(open(LOG_FILE).readlines()):
    if 'sample' in line:
        print(line.rstrip())
        break;

for line in reversed(open(LOG_FILE).readlines()):
    if 'another' in line:
        print(line.rstrip())
        break;
```

Desired output:

```
python  sample_prog.py
5 this is also INTERESTING sample line
3 this is another  line
```

Input file:

```
cat foo
1 this is a line
2 this is a another line
3 this is another  line
4 and this is INTERESTING sample line
5 this is also INTERESTING sample line
```

Note: It is safe to assume that '`sample`' and '`another`' will never be on the same line.

Comment: What if the last two lines have "sample", but not "another"? Or if the last line has both? I don't think your current implementation works correctly.

Comment: You're reading the file and iterating over the contents twice, which is surely a big performance loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consuming patterns from a predefined list (in case if input file is not so huge to be reversed):

```
LOG_FILE="foo.txt"

with open(LOG_FILE) as f:
    patterns = ['sample', 'another']

    for line in reversed(f.readlines()):
        if not patterns:   # all patterns were consumed
            break
        for pat in patterns[:]:
            if pat in line:
                print(line.strip())
                patterns.remove(pat)
                break
```

The output:

```
5 this is also INTRESTING sample line
3 this is another  line
```

Comment: No need to read the file and keep it in memory (`reversed(...)`).  No good to `strip()` the lines.  You would remove leading spaces, etc.

Comment: @Alfe, you mean this `reversed(f)` ?

Comment: Yep, I mean the whole `f.readlines()` already.  Try that with a 4GB log file and weep.

Comment: @Alfe, you wrong, `reversed(f)` will fail with `TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not reversible`

Comment: I'm right, but you misunderstood me.  I just pointed out weaknesses of your answer, not proposals what to remove (without adjusting the rest).  Look at my answer to understand what I mean how to do it.

Comment: @Alfe, I saw your answer, but I wouldn't talk about weaknesses, I could respond that your words sound weak - beware

Comment: Well, it's a weakness if your solution needs to keep the whole file in memory just to reverse the order of the lines only to find the last matches.

Comment: it would not be so critical for not huge files. I'm not against that the OP will accept your answer (to make you feel satisfied)

Answer (score 1):

```
last_sample = None
last_another = None

with open(LOG_FILE) as log_file:
  for line in log_file:
    if 'sample' in line:
      last_sample = line
    if 'another' in line:
      last_another = line

print(last_sample, end='')
print(last_another, end='')
```